# getting warning "unknown column favicon.ico"

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, mysql2

So i want to create a simple crud page using express and mysql2. When i request /:id and run query to search using WHERE, i get this warning even though i don't have that column.

```
"Unknown column 'favicon.ico' in 'where clause'
at PromiseConnection.execute"
```

My table

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| description | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| price       | decimal(6,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

My app.js

```
app.listen(3002, () => console.log(" Listening on Port 3002"));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.engine("ejs", ejsMate);
app.use(cookieParser("keyboard cat"));
app.use(session({ cookie: { maxAge: 60000 } }));
app.use(flash());

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    database: "shop",
    password: "password",
  });
  const [products] = await connection.execute("SELECT id,name FROM products");
  connection.end();
  console.log(req.session);
  res.render("", { products, message: req.flash("success") });
});

app.get("/add", (req, res) => {
  res.render("add");
});

app.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    database: "shop",
    password: "password",
  });
  const [product] = await connection.execute(
    `SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ${id}`
  );
  connection.end();
  res.render("product", { product });
});
```

Thanks before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you do not have a `favicon.ico` file in the directory where `app.js` is sitting. Browsers will look for the "Favourite Icon" to display in the browser tab (and other places).

Let's look at this line:

```
app.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
```

The `:id` is taking anything that comes from the path. So, if the URL is `http://localhost/app.js`, then the browser is going to ask for `http://localhost/favicon.ico`. `:id` will take `favicon.ico` as the value.

Then we come down to this section of code:

```
  const [product] = await connection.execute(
    `SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ${id}`
  );
```

There you go. This is why you get `Unknown column 'favicon.ico' in 'where clause'`. The SQL Query is literally:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = favicon.ico
```

**This is dangerous. Do not release this to production.**

The code is wide-open to SQL injections.

Be sure to add some validation to `:id` and to use prepared statements when querying the database. This will reduce — but not eliminate — the risk of a script-kiddy from ruining your day.

Comment: oh i see, i thought that "get" will only grab the url bar. And by validation to ":id", do you mean something like mongo sanitize?